# Why my C function works well, but got something wrong in PHP-Extension?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, php-extension

I need to call a .so shared library in PHP, so I write C code using "dlopen" and "dlsym" to do this, and it works.

sample.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*libfunc) (char *msg, int msglen);

int
sfunc(char *msg, int msglen);
```

sample.c:

```
#include "sample.h"

int
sfunc(char *msg, int msglen)
{
    void *lib;
    libfunc lib_func;
    int result;
    ...
    lib = dlopen(THE_LIB_PATH, RTLD_NOW);
    lib_func = (libfunc) dlsym(lib, THE_LIB_FUNC);
    ...
    result = lib_func(msg, msglen); // return 0 if success
    ...
    dlclose(lib);
    return result;
}
```

It always return 0.

And then I write a PHP extension as a wrapper, it takes PHP arguments and calls the C code before.

php_sample.c:

```
...
#include "sample.h"
...
PHP_FUNCTION(s_func)
{
    char *msg;
    long msglen;
    int result;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "s", &msg, &msglen) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

    result = sfunc(msg, (int) msglen);

    RETURN_LONG(result);
}
```

Then I added the extension(compiled to .so) to PHP and test the PHP function:

```
php -r "echo s_func("somestring");"
```

The call always failed, just return something not zero.

Why? Is there any difference?

Note: I tested this on one other computer and it works. So is there any problems about environments or something?

Comment: Note: system Ubuntu 16.04, using PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS ) and gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4), both tested computer are the same.

Comment: `PHP_FUNCTION(s_func)` - type is missing.  Isn't this supposed to be `PHP_FUNCTION(libfunc s_func)`?

Comment: I am ignorant in PHP-extension, but in `php -r "echo s_func("somestring");"`, don't you need 2 arguments?

Comment: @Nguaial see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.funcs.php), when passing a string to php function, use type specifier "s" and 2 local variables to catch it, so one argument is just ok. BTW, the php command should be php -r "echo s_func('somestring');", the quotes is wrong.

Comment: Don't you need php tag to reach out to PHP programmers?

Comment: @OP how did you try to debug? dlerror, gdb, strace, ltrace?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond dlerror has no output, the dl* functions works well, all things arn't work is the internal function in the .so library which dlopen opened. What make me confused is: same C code, work in pure C but not work when PHP extension calls it. All other code is very simple, so...I've not do any debug on it.